# Need help in deserializing unity asset bundle manifest file

Tags: unity-game-engine, yamldotnet

I need to deserialize main Unity asset bundle manifest in order to merge  them later (all in one).
How do you approach something like this :

```
ManifestFileVersion: 0
CRC: 4271548926
AssetBundleManifest:
  AssetBundleInfos:
    Info_0:
      Name: shared
      Dependencies: {}
    Info_1:
      Name: hotellobbyfivestar
      Dependencies:
        Dependency_0: shared
    Info_2:
      Name: plantsafety_workshop
      Dependencies:
        Dependency_0: shared
    Info_3:
      Name: plantsafety_factory
      Dependencies:
        Dependency_0: shared
    Info_4:
      Name: plantsafety_workshop_module3
      Dependencies:
        Dependency_0: shared
```

Please help!

Comment: What did you try until now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: getting error at Info_0: - expected token bug "found Start"

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking into this - just replace all of the Info_{0}: with "-" - do the same for Dependency_{0}: and finally replace all of the "{}" with "".

Unity Yaml is not a standard one, so you always need to do your procesing yourself.